# Magento increments before checkout

Tags: magento

In magento is there a way to force a user to have products of increments of 50 before they checkout?  I was able to figure out that they need 50 before they checkout but that doesn't prevent someone from ordering 51.  I sell matches and I've set up each product as their own fragrance so you could order 4 of one product and 57 of another but I want to force the person to have to checkout with a total of increments of 50.  So they could technically have 20 red matches, 30 green ones, 25 white, and 25 black.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So what you will want to do is to check if the total cart items is divisible by 50. The solution will be different depending on if you have an AJAX cart or the traditional POST cart. I'll assume you have the latter.

In your checkout validation page, you will want to add a check like this:

```
<?php
    // /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
    $cart           = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
    $cartItemsCount = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsSummaryQty();

    if( $cartItemsCount % 50 !== 0 ) {
        // Redirect and show error message
        $this->_getSession()->addError('Custom cart rule does not allow this');
        $this->_goBack();
    }
?>
```

*Note: the best way to make a core edit is to extend the file into your own module.*

Frontend validation is also a possibility, but it isn't fool-proof. Tricky users could get around this validation.

To make things easier for the user, you could have the quantity input be an [HTML5 number input](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number), and then have the step attribute increment in blocks of 50.

Obviously you will have to connect the dots here and do a bit of work, but this will get you started on it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, php Architect's book on Magento "Guide to e-commerce programming with Magento" goes over a custom module that does this sort of thing. Might be worth checking out.